# Making app service work invisible in background

Tags: java, android, kotlin, service, background

i have an app that runs a background service infinitely while also hiding the app icon and hiding it from the backstack so it wont be visible to the user while running using:

```
       val componentName = ComponentName(this, FullscreenActivity::class.java)
       p.setComponentEnabledSetting(
           componentName,
           PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
           PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
       )
```

this is how i launch the service from my fragment :

```
parentFragment?.activity?.startService(
                    Intent(
                        requireParentFragment().requireActivity().applicationContext,
                        RescueService::class.java
                    ).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                )
```

which successfully hides the icon and the app from backstack and the service keep running, also when i press the square button on my phone to show the backstack apps running i dont see the app there which is what i want, but if i click the "X" button to clear all backstack apps it also kills my app and my service dies even though the app does not appear there as i mentioned.

Any ideas what makes the service die after doing it? because it did not happen to couple of days ago before i did some changes in my app..

One of the changes i made is turnning my `Service` into `LifecycleService` because i needed my service to observe a livedata which needs a `LifecycleOwner`.Can it be the cause of my service to die when clearing the backstack?

All suggestions will be welcomed !

**EDIT1** - here is my `TestService`  that performs voice recording uses `WorkManager`.I call `hideApp()` to hide the icon from the phone and make the app invisible from the backstack :

```
class RecordingWork(
    context: Context,
    params: WorkerParameters
) : CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

    override val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {

        mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent)
        return Result.success()
    }
}

private lateinit var mSpeechRecognizer: SpeechRecognizer
private val mSpeechRecognizerIntent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)

class TestService : Service() {

    private lateinit var workManager: WorkManager

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d("TestService", "onStartCommand called")
        hideApp()
        prepareVoiceRecording()
        workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
        workManager.enqueue(OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<RecordingWork>().build())

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    fun prepareVoiceRecording() {
        mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(applicationContext)
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(
            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM
        )
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(
            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,
            Locale.getDefault()
        )
        mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(
            object : RecognitionListener {

                @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                override fun onError(i: Int) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onErrorCalled error is $i")
                    if (i == SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK || i == SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT || i == SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "error triggered")
                        mSpeechRecognizer.destroy()
                        prepareVoiceRecording()
                        workManager.enqueue(OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<RecordingWork>().build())

                    }
                }

                @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                override fun onResults(bundle: Bundle) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResults Called")
                    //getting all the matches
                    val matches = bundle
                        .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION)!!
                    workManager.enqueue(OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<RecordingWork>().build())
                }

 private fun hideApp() {
        val componentName = ComponentName(
            this,
            WelcomeScreenActivity::class.java
        )
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            componentName,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
        )
    }
```

this service does work to repeatedly record voice by rescheduling the Worker every time. but this service also dies when clearing backstack (even though the app does not appear there because of `hideApp()`)

Comment: I don't know what device and API are you using but if you're on Oreo or higher any background service should be killed unconditionally after 10-15 minutes. Only way to have permanent service is a foreground one, then it's up to user to go to system settings and hide notification.

Comment: i assume you are right since i did not actually tested and ran it  for long periods.. but anyway, i still havent reach that part.. my app dies once i clear the backstack even though it does not appear in backstack because i hide it and it's icon. i first want to understand how to fix that and then ill moving in to fixing the background/foreground thingy

Comment: Removing app from recents will kill its process (including all background services) unless it still has an active task or a foreground service. You won't receive any callbacks for it and can't circumvent it.

Comment: but the app does not appear in "recents" because of ```hideApp()``` function. and i am pretty sure it worked for me before.. i might have changed something but the app was not in recents and even if you would clear the recents the service still run and not dies.

Comment: Still no solution for this :P, i now run a foreground service with a foreground notification displaying but still once i clear all apps my service also dies.. any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Use workManager for long running background task (some device like Mi phone you need to white list the app for battery saver if you don't do that the OS will kill your app) and hiding of app icon not work in android X (only system apps can hide their icon)

Comment: my app does not get killed unless i click the "X" button in the backstack to clear all apps as i said. and yes my app icon is hidden so i guess it is working.. my problem is why the app also gets destroyed when clearing backstack apps even though it does not appear there

Comment: i created a new service  and used WorkManager now, still the service dies once i clear backstack :P and i used ```Service``` and not  ```LifecycleService``` so it has nothing to deal with that i guess

Comment: when you write all your code in worker class and set certain constraints when these constraint match you job is started. (If possible can you share your worker code.)

Comment: i added the code snippet including ```TestService``` and the Worker class ```RecordingWork```